# Public sample Logs table to demonstrate Kusto

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer

The [kusto tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/samples) references a **Logs** table. Is this data available publicly somewhere so as to try kusto out on a very large data store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The samples in the tutorial which reference the `StormEvents` table can be run against the `Samples` database in the `Help` cluster: https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples

Data sets used in other samples (such as those referencing the `Logs` table or the `Events` table) are not publicly available at this moment.